How to randomly select an integer from a list within a range?
I'm extracting some information from a CSV file into a list and would like a random value to be picked from that list. However, that value must exist within a specified range.
For example, if I have a list like so:
[12, 100, 144, 50, 65, 30, 500, 450, 6]

and I have a range 55-300, I want to be able to randomly select any value from within this list that satisfies the range. Say, 100, 144 or 65 but never 12, 6, 30, etc.
I haven't been able to find the solution to this anywhere, and the random module doesn't seem to have any functionality that supports this directly.
random.randrange() only produces a value from within a range, random.choice() only selects one element from a list, no range applies to it.
I'm essentially looking for a functionality that can possibly combine the two functions.

You can filter the numbers in your list to find the ones in the appropriate range, and pick one at random from those.
lst = [12, 100, 144, 50, 65, 30, 500, 450, 6]
number = random.choice([n for n in lst if 55 <= n <= 300])


if n in range(55, 301) will also work.

@matszwecja Seems uglier and slower, though. Any advantage?

@nocomment I disagree on the ugly part, I think it is more readable and flexible. It's also not gonna be significantly slower, in range has some decent optimisation to it.

Thanks, this works perfectly. List comprehension totally slipped my mind!

@matszwecja At least having to write 301 when the task says 300 is ugly to me. And in my testing, it's 3-7 times slower. Enough to make the whole statement take about twice as long.

import random

Your list of numbers
numbers = [12, 100, 144, 50, 65, 30, 500, 450, 6]

Specified range
min_value = 55
max_value = 300

Filter the list to only include numbers within the specified range
filtered_numbers = [num for num in numbers if min_value <= num <= max_value]

Select a random value from the filtered list
if filtered_numbers:
    random_value = random.choice(filtered_numbers)
    print(f"Random value within range: {random_value}")
else:
    print("No values within the specified range.")


Choosing until in range:
import random

lst = [12, 100, 144, 50, 65, 30, 500, 450, 6]

while not 55 <= (x := random.choice(lst)) <= 300:
    pass

print(x)

Attempt This Online!

What's the issue?

If you filter your list between those integers first, and then choose from that filtered list you will get your desired output:
lst = [12, 100, 144, 50, 65, 30, 500, 450, 6]
filtered_lst = [i for i in lst if i > 55 and i < 300]
random.choice(filtered_lst)

(change the < for <= if required etc)

I see basically the same answer was posted while I was writing this so I didn't see it.  I have not copied

Something like this should work for your scenario :
import random 
lst = [12, 100, 144, 50, 65, 30, 500, 450, 6]
find_num = lambda lst, low, upper : random.choice([item for item in lst if item >= low and item <= upper ]) 
print(find_num(lst,55,300))

